# AngularJS - HTTP Post a Form with an array

Tags: angularjs, arrays, forms, post

I need to `POST`a form with an array of values in there.

This is my HTML code:

```
<label>Name</label>
<input type="text" name="name" ng-model="vm.model.name">

<label>Behaviours</label>
<input type="text" name="behaviours[0].name" ng-model="vm.model.behaviours[0].name">
<input type="text" name="behaviours[1].name" ng-model="vm.model.behaviours[1].name">
```

Here's my controller code:

```
vm.model = {};

function submit() {
   MasterCompetence.save(vm.model)
            .success(...)
            .error(...)
}
```

And the request body is being send like this, with the behaviours as an Object:

```
{
   "name":"123",
   "behaviours": {
       "0": {
          "name":"Name 1","description":"Description 1"
       },
       "1": {
          "name":"Name 2","description":"Description 2"
       }
   }
}
```

But the Server API does not expect the names "0" and "1" of the behaviours. It expects:

```
{
   "name":"123",
   "behaviours": [
       {
          "name":"Name 1","description":"Description 1"
       },
       {
          "name":"Name 2","description":"Description 2"
       }
   ]
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I need the behaviours to be an array and not an object.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to make some changes as below.

Your HTML should look like this.

```
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text"  ng-model="vm.name">

    <label>Behaviours</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="vm.behaviours[0]['name']" ng-change="createModel()">
    <input type="text" ng-model="vm.behaviours[1]['name']" ng-change="createModel()">
    <pre>{{model}}</pre>
```

Your Js will look like this.

```
    $scope.vm ={};
    $scope.model = {};
    $scope.vm.behaviours =[];

    $scope.createModel = function() {
        $scope.model = {"name":$scope.vm.name,
        "behaviours":$scope.vm.behaviours};
    };
```